# Me pueden colaborar con este diseño en especifico

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy diseñando un marketplace, y quiero hacer un selector de cantidades de productos así como se muestra en la idea. Tengo un modal con un listview dentro para la lista, pero no sé cómo hacer para hacer el siguiente paso que es, al presionar el último botón, me abra otro modal con un input.

Aquí dejaré un poco del código

```
showModalBottomSheet(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            ),
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              final units = const [
                '1 unidad',
                '2 unidades',
                '3 unidades',
                '4 unidades',
                '5 unidades',
                'Más de 5 unidades',
              ];
              int _selectedIndex = 0;

              return Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.75,
                child: ListView.separated(
                  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: units.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Column(
                    children: [
                      if (index == 0)
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  '   Elige cantidad',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    fontFamily: 'inter',
                                  ),
                                ),
                                IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.close_rounded),
                                  onPressed: () => Modular.to.pop(context),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Divider(),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ListTile(
                        selected: index == _selectedIndex,
                        selectedColor: Colors.black,
                        selectedTileColor: Colors.grey[200],
                        title: Text(
                          units[index],
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          ),
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _selectedIndex = index;
                          });
                          Modular.to.pop(context);
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  separatorBuilder: (_, __) => const Divider(),
                ),
              );
            },
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido. El código va como texto. Lee [tour] y [ask] si aún no lo hiciste. Edita la pregunta para que sea mejor recibida.

Comment: ¿Cuál es realmente la pregunta? Ponla en el título: si alguien llega a tener un problema similar al tuyo, no va a poder encontrar la pregunta si te titula "Me pueden colaborar con este diseño". De nuevo, lee [ask].